# Unsure how JQuery interprets .each() and (this)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm reasonably new to JQuery, and I'm muddling through a bit, but by my logic the below *should* work. can you point out what's wrong?

I've got a bunch of repeating content blocks with classnames .acc-0, acc-1 and so on, which should hide and show `.plans-breakdown` when you click on `.open-link` button which sits inside the block(s)

This is the example with `.acc-1`

```
$('.acc-1').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.open-link').on('click',function() {
        $('.plans-breakdown').not(this).css('display','none');
        $(this).find('.plans-breakdown').fadeToggle(600);
    });
});
```

HTML;

```
<div class="schedule-plan acc-0">
<div class="open-link">Floor plan acc-0</div>
    <div class="plans-breakdown">
        content here
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="schedule-plan acc-1">
<div class="open-link">Floor plan acc-1</div>
    <div class="plans-breakdown">
        content for acc-1 here
    </div>
</div>
```

I want this function to only work on the specific code block. In this example `.acc-1`. So I've wrapped the function in a `$('.acc-1').each(function(){}`

I've used `(this)` to specify the correct `.open-link` button which needs to trigger the function. Also, on the `.fadeToggle` action, to target the instance of `.plan-breakdown` which is nested inside `.acc-1`

Check out my fiddle, notice how the first block works (.acc-0). When I use `.each` 
it doesn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/Q4zmS/2/

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4zmS/4/)

You can simply use:

```
// for every element with a acc- class...
$('[class*=acc-]').on('click', function () {
    // hide all elements previously shown
    $('.plans-breakdown').css('display', 'none');
    // fade in the child element
    $(this).find('.plans-breakdown').fadeToggle(600);
    // for all active links, remove the active class
    $('.open-link').removeClass('active');
    // add the active class to the child link
    $(this).find('.open-link').addClass('active');
});
```

I'd also add:

```
.plans-breakdown{
    display:none;
}
```

To your CSS, removing the need for the JS:

```
$('.plans-breakdown').css('display', 'none');
```

And change your CSS to the below as you have nested rules, which is invalid:

```
.schedule-plan {
    display:block;
    padding-top:.3em;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.active {
    color:black;
}
.plans-breakdown {
    margin:1em 0 2em 0;
    cursor:default;
}
.plans-breakdown {
    display:none;
}
```